# Display README.md in repository directories

Tags: github, readme

Github repo I'm referencing: https://github.com/Dallas-Marshall/PersonalProjects/tree/master/discord_bot

I have a Personal Projects Repository on Github and have a README.md file in the root folder explaining the repo. However, the issue I am having is that inside a directory of the repo I have created another README.md file to explain that specific project but Github is not displaying it.

I have ensured the file is named correctly, is up to date on Github and have scanned settings to try and find an option to display it to no avail as yet.

Does anyone know how to get this file to display when viewing the directory that I have linked above.

Many Thanks,
Dallas Marshall

Comment: Your readme seems to be empty https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dallas-Marshall/PersonalProjects/master/discord_bot/README.md or here: https://github.com/Dallas-Marshall/PersonalProjects/blob/master/discord_bot/README.md

Comment: (Facepalm) I had committed the file but not yet pushed to Github, Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your readme in the [linked repo](https://github.com/Dallas-Marshall/PersonalProjects/tree/master/discord_bot) folder is [empty](https://github.com/Dallas-Marshall/PersonalProjects/blob/a316cc71e00913ac59e0b17d8888171eb78f10fc/discord_bot/README.md). GitHub will start displaying it once it got content in it.

Comment: (Facepalm) I had committed the file but not yet pushed to Github, Thanks mate!